# jQuery - addClass() mouseover

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery effect where if the user mouse over the reply image, the image would change to another image. The problem I am having is that when you mouse over another object, which is set to addClass() for the reply image, this new reply image does not change its image when mouseovered.

Demo of my problem:
http://www.sfu.ca/~jca41/stuph/jQueryTest/jQueryTest.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".red").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css("color","red");
        $(this).addClass("reply");
    });
    $(".red").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).css("color","black");
        $(this).removeClass("reply");
    });

    $(".reply").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(reply_h.png)"); 
    });
    $(".reply").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(reply.png)"); 
    });

});
```

Comment: *Note:* You should chain your jQuery statements, like this: `$(this).css("color","black").removeClass("reply");`

Comment: Cool. Didn't know you can do that. Just made the modification. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "new" reply image is part of a CSS background. Therefore it's not actually part of the DOM, and therefore jQuery can't modify it or even detect when it's moused over.

To get the result you want, you need to make the second button part of the DOM and hide/show it instead: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/tJwUW/3/

HTML:

```
Mouseover the reply image and it changes states
<div class="reply"></div>

<hr><hr><hr>

<div class="red">
<div class="reply"></div> <!-- added -->
Mouseover this, then mouseover the new reply image 
and notice it does not change state
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.reply {
    background-image:url('reply.png');
    height: 18px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.red .reply { /* added */
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".red").mouseover(function() { // modified
    $(this).css("color", "red").find(".reply").css('visibility','visible');
});
$(".red").mouseout(function() { // modified
    $(this).css("color", "black").find("reply").css('visibility','hidden');
});

$(".reply").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(reply_h.png)"); 
});
$(".reply").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(reply.png)"); 
});
```

Comment: In that case, what are my possible solutions? Should I use some sort of innerHTML tactic?

Comment: There is one bug that I've noticed. When you mouseout, the reply image does not disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you add on mouseover a class that has the event on mouseover to change the bg-image?
Wouldn't it be much easier directly on mouseover of .red to change the image?

Answer (score 0):

Its because when you mouseover the div with class 'red' then 'reply' class adds to it and its also comes in a mouseover state.

**Solution :**  keep blank div inside the div with class 'red' before the text:

```
<div class="red"><div></div>demo text</div>
```

and modify your script to

```
$(".red").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("color","red");
    $(this).children('div').addClass("reply");
});
$(".red").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css("color","black");
    $(this).children('div').removeClass("reply");
});

$(".reply").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(reply_h.png)"); 
});
$(".reply").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(reply.png)"); 
});
```

Comment: I actually used mblase75's answer as his post was before yours :(
Sorry, wish I could accept multiple answers, but thank you very much :)